# shell script (KSH) + set file to param & perform test between param and string

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting, ksh

in my linux machine red-hat 5.1 - in ppp file - I have only the signature.pl string !!!

- remark - third application write the signature.pl string in to ppp file

I set ppp file in $a param
And compare $a with signature.pl

But as all see here this not equal - why ? or if I have empty space? 
How to solve this?

```
    # more /var/tmp/ppp
    signature.pl
    # a=`cat /var/tmp/ppp`
    # echo $a
    signature.pl
    # [[ $a = signature.pl ]] && echo equal
```

or

```
    # [[ $a == signature.pl ]] && echo equal
```

diff example that works ! - from ksh shell (LINUX RED-HAT 5.1)

```
[u@h w]# echo signature.sh > file
[u@h w]# cat file
signature.sh
[u@h w]# a=`cat file`  
[u@h w]# echo $a
signature.sh
[u@h w]# [[ $a = signature.sh ]] && echo eq

 its print "eq"
```

Comment: Your "real" example compares `signature.sh` and `signature.pl`...they aren't the same.

Comment: this is a nother example (I fix it), on both they have the same ishhu

Comment: It works for me. What does this tell you? `echo "${.sh.version}"` What happens if you do: `[[ $a = $a ]] && echo eq`

Comment: yes Dennis now its work also for me I create new file in place of ppp , not clearly what was wrong , for for the first case the original question I still have problem - third application write the signature.pl string in to ppp file so I cant say what wrong here in the ppp file by vi I see only this string ( I update my results on the second case )

Comment: Run `/var/tmp/ppp` through `od -c` - it might contain some unprintables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *two* equal signs:

```
[[ $a == signature.pl ]] && echo equal
```

Comment: I already tried it it also not work .....!!!